# no WiFi and Ethernet connection on msi gaming edge wifi. Where and how do I install the drivers if possible

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ethernet, msi

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my newly build PC but it isn't recognizing my WiFi & Ethernet device. I downloaded Windows 10 on it before that and the Internet connection is just fine but when I use Ubuntu I get nothing. Not even a "No WiFi found" but "no WiFi adapter found". I already went to "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" like most forums say but there it's only showing me drivers for my graphics card. The WiFi and Ethernet devices are mounted on the Motherboard (msi B550 gaming edge WiFi) and the driver for the motherboard is only available for Windows 10 64bit. In the specification its says that the "Realtek® RTL8125B 2.5G LAN" driver is used but it is running on a "Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200". I don't know which exact driver to use and even if I knew I don't know how to install it on Linux because I am new to it.

The only question coming close to my Problem is [Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=258479) but it's using Arch Linux and I didn't understand a thing on what to do.

**How to I get Internet in form of WiFi or Ethernet?**

Right now I get my WiFi using USB Tethering from my Phone but it is really slow.

Here is the *important* Output I get when typing `lspci -k`:

```
29:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
    DeviceName: RTL8111E Giga LAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
2a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

And for `ifconfig`:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2547  bytes 209036 (209.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2547  bytes 209036 (209.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:29:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2a:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc50ffff memory:fc510000-fc513fff
```

I also followed a lot of tutorials that promised to fix this problem by installing additional drivers but all of them didn't work.
I think it has to do something with the build in WiFi and Ethernet. And pleas give me easy to follow institutions. I am new to Linux/Ubuntu and I don't know the terminology yet.
Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: Please ask one question regarding Wi-Fi and Ethernet. These are different issues.

Answer (score 2):

I have found my solution. I downloaded the driver for realtek ethernet and entert the comands as good as i could and it worked.

Comment: Download the latest RTL8125B Linux driver from Realtek:  [https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software]   Unpack the archive and cd into the release directory.   Build and install the driver with the command `sudo ./autorun.sh`.  You will need to rebuild the driver each time the kernel is updated.

Comment: For me the [Realtek GBE driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything i found this to work for my MSI GE66 with killer wifi 6

Enter the following commands into a Terminal one line at a time.

1. Download the Latest Git and Build-Essential packages

```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt-get install -y git
    sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

2. Download the Iwlwifi-Firmware.git repository

```
    git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
    cd linux-firmware
    sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
    cd ..
```

3. Create the Backported Iwlwifi Driver for your current setup

```
    git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
    cd backport-iwlwifi
    sudo make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
    sudo make -j4
    sudo make install
```

This command might be necessary to force your machine to use the Driver from boot:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot your Computer and verify it’s working!

Best of luck

Comment: I confirm this works. I think we may need to rebuild the driver for each new kernel. :(

Comment: How would you do that when there's no wifi or internet connection? Stuck here.