# No ethernet on a MSI MPG B550 Gaming Carbon WiFi motherboard

Tags: drivers, 20.04, msi

I just got a MSI MPG B550 Gaming Carbon WiFi motherboard. I installed Ubuntu 20.04. When it booted to the OS it will only see wifi and no ethernet connection. Do I need to get drivers in order to get this to work? Seem odd that the wifi worked out of the box, but no ethernet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since your motherboard does in fact have an Ethernet port, I think it is a driver issue.

This site may help:

[no WiFi and Ethernet connection on msi gaming edge wifi. Where and how do I install the drivers if possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299842/no-wifi-and-ethernet-connection-on-msi-gaming-edge-wifi-where-and-how-do-i-inst)

and so might these:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=258479

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=327043

However,on the MSI website there do not seem to be any driver downloads for Linux. The links above may be your best bet, and may provide the best help for your query and issue.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to have solved it with the mystery for the driver location not stated. A search on that model lead to the third link.

[no WiFi and Ethernet connection on msi gaming edge wifi. Where and how do I install the drivers if possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299842/no-wifi-and-ethernet-connection-on-msi-gaming-edge-wifi-where-and-how-do-i-inst)

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Realtek%C2%AE+RTL8125B+2.5G+LAN+linux+driver

https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with my MSI B550 Gaming edge WiFi board and Ubuntu 20.04.

Running `lshw` gave me:

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

**Steps to fix the issue:**

Download the 2.5G Ethernet Linux Driver r8125 from [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software).

Unpack the tarball with:

```
tar vjxf r8125-9.aaa.bb.tar.bz2
```

Change to the directory:

```
cd r8125-9.aaa.bb
```

Gave execution permissions and run `autorun.sh`:

```
chmod +x autorun.sh
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

In case, the previous command did not work, you can use:

```
sudo sh autorun.sh
```