# Ethernet/LAN not detected on Gigabyte B550 Motherboard w. dual boot windows/ubuntu20.04 on separate SSDs

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, ethernet, realtek

**ISSUE**

Originally my motherboard was working fine with only Windows. After adding a separate Ubuntu SSD, my ethernet LAN port has stopped being recognised, both by Windows and by Ubuntu. I don't *think* it is a duplicate of the many driver issues seen on askubuntu, as I explored that, but I can't confirm if it's a problem with the board itself or something else I don't understand.

If you need ANY more information, either from Windows or from Ubuntu, will share whatever's needed.

**PC Specs:**

- OSs - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 + Windows 10
- Kernel - 5.8.0-50-generic
- CPU - Ryzen 7 5800x
- Mobo - Gigabyte Aorus B550 Elite AX V2 - [link here](https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Motherboard/B550-AORUS-ELITE-AX-V2-rev-10)
- Disks - 1 Samsung 980 PRO 1 TB PCIe 4.0 (Windows 10), 1 Samsung 970 EVO Plus 1 TB PCIe 3.0 (Ubuntu 20.04)
- GPU - Nvidia RTX 3080 FE
- RAM - 32GB (2x16GB) Corsair DDR4 Vengeance LPX

**Steps Taken:**

1. Other similar posts have said it might be a driver issue. Following posts similar to [this one here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319074/no-ethernet-on-a-msi-mpg-b550-gaming-carbon-wifi-motherboard) I manually installed Realtek drivers on Ubuntu and Windows. This did not solve the problem.
2. `sudo lshw -C network` does not show the Ethernet as being available. I think what I should see here is something like: `*-network UNCLAIMED    description: Ethernet controller    product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller` but that doesn't show:

   ```
   ~ ❯ sudo lshw -C network                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     *-network                 
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
      logical name: wlp6s0
      version: 1a
      serial: c8:b2:9b:a1:1a:3a
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode ip=192.168.0.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
      resources: irq:38 memory:fc500000-fc503fff
   ```
3. Tested the ethernet cable from my router on a Mac, worked perfectly fine, so it's not a cable issue.
4. Disabled all sorts of FastBoot, Wake-From-LAN etc etc in both Windows and BIOS, no changes
5. `cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`:

   ```
   # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
   network:
     version: 2
     renderer: NetworkManager
   ```
6. `sudo ip a`

   ```
   ~ ❯ sudo ip a
   1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   2: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether c8:b2:9b:a1:1a:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.0.22/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp6s0
      valid_lft 84463sec preferred_lft 84463sec
   inet6 fe80::63a6:76c2:cb97:be14/64 scope link noprefixroute 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   ```
7. `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

   ```
   ~ ❯ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
   [main]
   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

   [ifupdown]
   managed=true

   [device]
   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
   ```
8. `lspci -knn`:

   ```
   ~ ❯ lspci -knn
   00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex [1022:1480]
           Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex [1022:1480]
   00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU [1022:1481]
           Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU [1022:1481]
   00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
   00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge [1022:1483]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge [1022:1483]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
   00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
   00:03.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge [1022:1483]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
   00:05.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
   00:07.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
   00:07.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] [1022:1484]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
   00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] [1022:1484]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 61)
           Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd FCH SMBus Controller [1458:5001]
           Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
   00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
           Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd FCH LPC Bridge [1458:5001]
   00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0 [1022:1440]
   00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1 [1022:1441]
   00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2 [1022:1442]
   00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3 [1022:1443]
           Kernel driver in use: k10temp
           Kernel modules: k10temp
   00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4 [1022:1444]
   00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5 [1022:1445]
   00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6 [1022:1446]
   00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7 [1022:1447]
   01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a80a]
           Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
           Kernel driver in use: nvme
           Kernel modules: nvme
   02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ee]
           Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1142]
           Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
           Kernel modules: xhci_pci
   02:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43eb]
           Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1062]
           Kernel driver in use: ahci
           Kernel modules: ahci
   02:00.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43e9]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   03:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   03:08.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   03:09.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43ea]
           Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
           Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a801]
           Kernel driver in use: nvme
           Kernel modules: nvme
   06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
           Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
           Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
           Kernel modules: iwlwifi
   07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2206] (rev a1)
           Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1467]
           Kernel driver in use: nvidia
           Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
   07:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1aef] (rev a1)
           Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1467]
           Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
           Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
   08:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function [1022:148a]
           Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function [1022:148a]
   09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
           Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
   09:00.1 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP [1022:1486]
           Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP [1022:1486]
           Kernel driver in use: ccp
           Kernel modules: ccp
   09:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller [1022:149c]
           Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller [1458:5007]
           Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
           Kernel modules: xhci_pci
   09:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
           DeviceName: Realtek ALC1220
           Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1458:a0cf]
           Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
           Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
   ~ ❯ lspci -knn | grep eth
   ~ ❯
   ```
9. Reached out to Gigabyte Technical Support. They suggested to upgrade BIOS from F12 to F13h. This did not solve the problem.

**Conclusions**

I am not familiar with Windows AT ALL (only use for Steam gaming), but after doing some Googling, I think the same issue applies there, where the Ethernet Network Adaptor does not exist or can't be detected. I would like to stress, it *was* available in the past, but now is not.
The same applies on Ubuntu, so for both OSs, installing the Drivers doesn't solve the problem because it's not detected as existing in the first place.

What I would love, is either a solution to this if anyone has any ideas, or confirmation that it's a hardware fault so I can return my MOBO or buy some additional PCIEX Network adapter

Comment: Several onboard devices can be enabled/disabled at the UEFI ("BIOS") settings. Have you checked that? It's either disabled in UEFI or the Ethernet is now defective. When a device disappears simultaneously in two completely different OSes it isn't drivers or anything software/OS related, it's ALWAYS hardware (or firmware settings).

Comment: Yours is a common story for motherboards using the RTL8125. It works for a bit, then becomes finicky as heck. Only group of people that seem to have any luck with it are [Hackintosh enthusiasts](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/345186-please-help-ethernet-not-working-in-gigabyte-b550/?do=findComment&comment=2737894). The most common advice is to disable the faulty device in the BIOS and buy a PCI Express card.

Comment: Here's the best I could do for sharing what BIOS settings I have: http://imgur.com/a/WnuHAQr

Answer (score 0):

If you can somehow try to find what device you have as a network adapter - name, id. If it was shown in windows and working all the time for sure it has to be present in linux - if it's not psychically damaged or old, or missing.
After that try to find a good driver for it, depending on your kernel/linux.
In my case, i shared internet via usb from the phone, and downloaded via pamac/pacman one of the drivers available for the kernel and device i was using.
But of course i had to spend some night hours exploring my inexperience with linux, messing up the network manager config to unusable, install and uninstalling drivers or trying to compile a driver while not having internet and transfering files via usb stick because somehow internet was working there.
Yeah, i like drivers and linux.
Anyways, linux is cool. Still would stick around.