# MSI X670E Tomahawk Wifi motherboard doesn't support network on ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet, msi

I setup a new machine and the ethernet and wifi isn't working on the motherboard. I plugged in a USB-ethernet adapter, and I have internet. I contacted MSI, and they say they don't support linux which is why the network doesn't work.

I tried usuing Zorin 16.3 (Ubuntu 22) as well as Ubuntu 23.04, and neither work.

I tried the steps here, but didn't work:

[no WiFi and Ethernet connection on msi gaming edge wifi. Where and how do I install the drivers if possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299842/no-wifi-and-ethernet-connection-on-msi-gaming-edge-wifi-where-and-how-do-i-inst)

[No ethernet on a MSI MPG B550 Gaming Carbon WiFi motherboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319074/no-ethernet-on-a-msi-mpg-b550-gaming-carbon-wifi-motherboard) (restarted machine after as well, no luck)

nmcli device status / netstat -i / ip link show do not show any adapters for wifi/mobo ethernet

It only shows the USB-ethernet and the loopback.

Any ideas how this could be resolved if any? I want to use the mobo ethernet, and would also like to have the wifi adapter available for future use. Motherboard: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-X670E-TOMAHAWK-WIFI

Side note: don't buy MSI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Upload a probe to  https://linux-hardware.org/ and share the link.

Comment: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=e57d71e056

Comment: It looks like support for it has been added in kernel 6.3.12. I'll try to upgrade the kernel and report back.

Comment: installed 6.3.13 and nothing, installed 6.4.7 and nothing. Guess onboard ethernet just a no-go. I very much dislike MSI now :(